# How to use tun device in Windows C program

Tags: c, linux, windows, networking, tun

I have used tun devices on Linux before and need to port my code on Windows. I have installed tun/tap driver from OpenVPN on Windows, but I am not able to figure out how to create a device handle for that tun device in Windows C program.

Basically I need help creating the tun device and getting the handle.

The code I use on Linux is as follows (similar to the example on kernel.org)

```
int mktun (char * dev, int flags, struct ifreq * ifr) {

    int fd, stat;
    char * clonedev = "/dev/net/tun";


    /* Get the file descriptor from the tun clone to use as input to ioctl() */
    if ( (fd = open(clonedev, O_RDWR) ) < 0 )
        return fd;

    /* Now prepare the structure ifreq for ioctl() */
    memset(ifr, 0, sizeof(*ifr));                   /* reset memory to 0 */
    ifr->ifr_flags = flags;             /* set the flags IFF_TUN or IFF_TAP and IFF_NO_PI */

    if (*dev)
        strcpy(ifr->ifr_name, dev);

    /* Now we try and create a device */
    if ( (stat = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) ifr) ) < 0 ) {
        perror("ioctl()");
        close(fd);
        return stat;
    }

    /* Now write back the name of the interface to dev just to be sure */
    strcpy(dev, ifr->ifr_name);

    /* Now return the file descriptor that can be used to talk to the tun interface */
    return fd;
}
```